# xamarin agent don't enable login button when connecting to a mac

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to connect a visual studio 2015 community with a mac for using to compile a xamarin app but I'm unable to connect to the mac.
Windows10 with visual studio 2015 community, macos sierra with xamarin studio and xcode.
I have all installed, configured and updated, the firewall on mac is off, the sharing is ok, I also tested the ssh connection from windows to the mac and on terminal the connection is successfull.
The only thing is the xamarin agent from visual studio->tools->options->xamarin->iOS setting, the mac is visible, y try to connect but the login button never enables to do the login attempt.
[Image of xamarin agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugc2G.png).
I tryed to open visual studio on admin mode but ther is no way to enable this button.
Can someone please advise?
Best regards
Sergio E.

Comment: HI Sergio, sometimes Visual Studio is quote slow to launch on Mac the Designer Agent or it lost the connection. Personally I restart Visual Studio. Do you allow everyone on the mac to remote login?

Comment: Yes, Enrico, all users are allowed to connect, there are no firewall enabled on mac.
Restarted visual studio, then the mac, then  the windows laptop, opened the visual studio with administrative rights but nothing happnes.
The login button is disabled  even with right user and password fields fulfilled.

Comment: The final solution is: there is a bug in the version a was using, updating xamarin to the lastest version fix the problem.